# Posting the datas through URL

Tags: php, client-side, serverside-javascript

I like to pass the values to the webpage. I am having the array in which the values are stored dynamically. I like to pass this array to webpage through URL, website is in PHP Language. I am not aware of the variables present inside the PHP page.Did we have any types of technique or script to get the variable names which used in PHP code from the client side.

Comment: you want to pass data from where to where? from server to client or from client to server?

Comment: If you want to know what is going on into the server-side (PHP vars, functions, etc.), you cannot make it from client-side (Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

using method=get and $_Get method ,

Information sent from a form with the GET method is visible to everyone (it will be displayed in the browser's address bar) and has limits on the amount of information to send.

example

```
   <form action="welcome.php" method="get">
     Name: <input type="text" name="fname" />
     Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
     <input type="submit"  value="Submit"/>
     </form>
```

Welcome.php(get the value from url)

```
          <?php 
             echo $_GET["fname"]; 
             echo $_GET["age"];

          ?>
```